# Is log-linear regression a generalized linear model?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model

Does log-linear regression fall into the class of generalized linear models? Here I'm defining "log-linear regression" as the model $\log(y) = x'\beta + \eta$ where $\eta \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$.

Thanks.

Comment: What does $\eta$ refer here? Error? If so, why do you specify error distribution?

Comment: @T.E.G. Yes, $\eta$ is the noise (not the error). I specify its distribution because this is what makes it "statistics" :-).  See https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~bee/courses/scribe/lec_09_11_2013.pdf or http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/mreg/15/lectures/06/lecture-06.pdf.

Comment: Please see my answer below. What you call noise ($\eta$) is not different from error ($\epsilon$) here. See the first link you posted, page 2: $\epsilon \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$. It is also called the error distribution.

Comment: Perhaps the nearest model to yours that would be what is normally counted as a GLM would be a GLM with variance proportional to mean (which implies the Gamma) and log link.

Comment: http://andrewgelman.com/2006/04/10/log_transformat/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, loglinear models *for contingency tables* are considered as generalized linear models (Fox 2016). They are sometimes called Poisson regression for contingency tables (Bilder & Loughlin 2015). In the case of Poisson regression, we have a response random variable $Y$, and $p \geq 1$ explanatory variables, $x_1,\dots,x_p$, and for observations $i=1,\ldots,n$, we assume that

$$Y_i \sim Po(\mu_i)$$

where

$$\mu_i = \exp(\beta_0+\beta_1x_{i1}+\ldots+\beta_px_{ip}).$$

So, the generalized linear model has a Poisson random component, linear predictor (systematic component), and link function (*log-link*):

$$\log(\mu)=\beta_0+\beta_1x_1+\ldots+\beta_px_p.$$

Looks similar to your equation. However, first, you seem to transform the outcome, $y$, directly. So, it looks like you follow what Agresti (2015:6) calls transformed-data approach (i.e., $E[g(y_i)] = \beta_0+\beta_ix_{i1}$ instead of $g[E(y_i)]= \beta_0+\beta_ix_{i1}$, $g$ is the link function). And second, (I think) you specify error distribution, $\eta \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$. As you can see in this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/212433/109647), in GLMs, "You don't specify the "error" distribution, you specify the conditional distribution of the response." The exception is latent variable approach.

To answer your question: yes, log-linear regression falls into the class of generalized linear models, but your model looks like a linear regression model with a log-transformed outcome.

---

Agresti, Alan. 2015. *Foundations of Linear and Generalized Linear Models*. Hoboken, NJ: Wiley.

Bilder, Christopher R. and Thomas M. Loughlin. 2015. *Analysis of Categorical Data with R*. Boca Raton, London and New York: CRC Press.

Fox, John. 2016. *Applied Regression Analysis and Generalized Linear Models*. 3rd ed. Los Angeles: Sage Publications.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I did in fact mean what I wrote, that $\log(y) \sim N(x'\beta, \sigma^2)$ which I know is different from Poisson regression (which is a GLM). So my question was whether this log-normal linear model was a GLM. But given your response, it seems like it's not since the error distribution is specified rather than the conditional distribution of the response.

Comment: Upon reflection, it seems like my model is a GLM such that $Y \mid (x, \beta, \sigma^2) \sim \text{Lognormal}(x^\top\beta, \sigma^2)$. This is not very deep but it is the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $x$ and the model.

Comment: @ted, Well, yes, I think using lognormal as link function works, but this means you move from a transformed-data approach to GLM and, although similar, this is still different from the model in your question. Andrew Gelman's post in generic_user's comment explains this briefly too: "...the key difference being the relation between the predicted value and the variance."

Comment: @ted, Although rather software specific, you might want to check this question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21447/how-to-specify-a-lognormal-distribution-in-the-glm-family-argument-in-r